# Asp.NET Core FindByNameAsync Can't Find A User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use ASP.NET Core Identity and try "FindByNameAsync" method to get a user with username. I am sure there is a user with the username. But "FindByNameAsync" can't find the user. "GetByUserName" is my method and it queries db with username and it found the user as i expect. Has FindByNameAsync a bug or?

```
//this is can't find the user with username
var appUser = await UserService.FindByNameAsync(userName);

//this is my method and it works well
var appUser = UserService.GetByUserName(userName);
```

Comment: What implementation of `UserService` are you using? Didnt you want to use `UserManager<T>`

Comment: EF Core is open-source and in use by millions of developers. It also has a complete test suite and rigorous development policies that ensure that all code, contributed by the community or by Microsoft is peer-reviewed before being merged. Long and short, *assume* you're the problem, not that EF has a "bug".

Answer (score 0):

I'm normally using UserManager to find the info about the user

```
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
    }

    public async Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string username)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    }

    public async Task<User> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    }

    public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

You can view my full source code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/6cafbd5591/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Helper/Services/UserService.cs)